# SpringBoot profile-based services

Tags: maven, spring-boot, properties, shared-libraries

I try to make my SpringBoot App code "DRY" again.

I have several snippets which which look similar which I would like to pack into a @Service method within a MVN library which is shared across all SpringBoot Apps.

Problem here is currently that these code is using profile (debug, QA, Live) based properties. Like the other APIs URLs. 
e.g.:

```
@Value("${myapp.communication.url}")
private String communicationUrl;
```

...And other settings. But inside a library it uses only the Library properties.

Whats a current best practice for this?

Is it possible to to set all properties (dev, qa, live) in the Library and the implementing App profile is deciding what properties will be used from the library?

Thanks for any links & hints!